# Battery indicator show incorrect battery level

Tags: 18.04, laptop, battery

I'm getting inconsistent battery levels being show in the battery indicator.

[image]

[image]

Also, the red font seems to show up at 29%, anyway to customise this?

Answer (score 0):

Either you battery is not working good these days. Or you can try TLP battery service just install this apt-get install tlp. It will tell the exact details of your battery level and battery disintegration levels. Have a look at here https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

Comment: Well battery deg isn't an issue for me, also TLP would be a bad idea if i'm using powertop too no?